# ListView display issue List shifts to right on iPhone and iPad

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, listview, jquery-mobile

**j-query mobile** - `ListView display issue`, List shirts to right on `iPhone and iPad`.

I can't get the iPhone to display `ListView` items correctly.
It seems to have shifted the whole list about 15 px to the right - cutting off part of the right arrow and leaving a GAP on the left side of the list. Header and footer looks fine everything centers nicely but the `LISTVIEW` is an issue with `Iphone 5 and Ipad`.

Looks perfect on android and Desktop;
Screen Shot of Issue: http://montemayorstudios.com/mobile/iPhone-issue.png

Mobile Website Link: http://montemayorstudios.com/mobile/

Thank You for any Help - Please email; Marcel(at)MontemayorStudios.com

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be caused by the `align="center"` attribute of your `content` div.
Removing this attribute fixes the offset.
By the way, you should use only one `content` div on each of your `page` div in jQuery Mobile